# Using mobile phone's geolocation in background mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm planning to develop a webbased location-based mobile application (primarily focussing on Android, but would be cool get it working on iOS, too), which will use the smartphone's geolocation for notification purposes.
I've already looked around and I'm quite sure that I will use PhoneGap/Cordova for the implementation stuff (there is a very nice [plugin](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation), which enables a background geolocation update), but to be sure that this is not the one and only solution (except of a native app), I would like to ask for your help.

As Google Chrome (for Android) got some cool new features in recent time as the [Push-Notification functionalitiy](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/reaching-and-re-engaging-users-on.html) or the [Page to Homescreen feature](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/reaching-and-re-engaging-users-on.html) **do you know whether it is possible to use a geolocation-background-functionality using Googles Chrome or at least without any additional Framework?**

And yes...I am aware of the fact that the best way would be a native application implementation.
Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the geo location using html 5:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: But will this method also be called, when the website is in the background mode? Like closing the browser, or even turning the screen off?

Comment: I've tried the HTML5 geolocation-functionality using [some snippets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/#toc-final)...as far as I see, a website, which asks for geolocation-permission, is not able to update the device's geolocation until the website is in the foreground. Do you mean by "android service" a native android application?

Comment: yes, this is the best solution for background operations

Comment: Of course...it would be the best solution, but that's out of the question ;) I'll definitely (have to) develop it using web technologies...